# Loading file in MatLab

Tags: matlab

Attempting to follow this tutorial https://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/objectdetectortrainingdata.html, I have aerial photos of parking lots in which I want cars to automatically be counted by the program. (If I am going in the wrong direction or there is an easier solution please let me know!).

My Error:

```
Warning: Variable 'carsGroundTruth' not found. 
In carDetection (line 3)
```

My Code:

```
imageDir = fullfile(matlabroot, 'toolbox', 'vision', 'visiondata', 'carImages');
addpath(imageDir);
load('cars.mat','carsGroundTruth')
```

Why won't cars.mat load? I have tried putting it in the MATLAB file within Documents, and also the imageDir referenced in line 1.

Comment: You probably don't have variable called `carsGroundTruth` inside the file `cars.mat`. You can load the whole file with `load('cars.mat')`

Comment: Are you sure `'carImages'` is a valid folder within `'visiondata'`? I can't find that in any of my recent Matlab installation folders...

Comment: Yeah will have to look into adding a variable, I just used the ImageLabler app to generate the .mat file drawing rectangles around cars. Wolfie I added the carImages folder in there in the spirit of following the tutorial.

Comment: Just try dragging and dropping the `.mat` file into your workspace so you can check you're trying to access the right variables

Comment: It's a really bad idea to put user data into the `matlabroot` directory. Upgrading to a new version of MATLAB could cause you to lose that data. Use your home directory instead.